# Operators overloading in c++ to search inverse of matrix

Tags: c++

I need to create an overload that will calculate the inverse matrix. I already know how to write code without an operator. But I still don't understand how to implement this by overloading the operator, and which operator to use. I just need an example of an declaration operator's function.

Comment: `and which operator to use.` Neither do we. unary minus or NOT might be a good choice, but that's up to you.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading) help you get started? It covers the basics of operator overloading. I'm not sure what operator you'd want to overload for this though, since "inverse of" isn't really something that tends to have an operator to begin with.